# Initialize a GitHub repository after creation

Tags: github

I created a GitHub repository (for SVN use) and chose not to initialize it in the wizard. Now, I cannot find an option to initialize the repository (I do not have a Git client installed, and I prefer not to). SVN access does not work properly since no master branch exists.

Can I still initialize the repository?

I would not like to delete and re-create the repository since I have set up all collaborators and such.

Comment: When you go to https://github.com/{username}/{reponame} does it not show a "Quick setup" screen?

Comment: Yes, it does. This screen looks like this: http://blog-imgs-45-origin.fc2.com/m/y/p/mypace75/github.png But which option will allow me to initialize the repository with an empty master branch without an extra git client, so I can start adding files from my private, offline (option 4 does not work) SVN repo?

Comment: In your SVN repo you should be able to follow the steps in "…or push an existing repository from the command line"

Comment: This requires a git client (I was trying to do everything with just an SVN client, but if you fail to initialize the git repo when creating it, you are stuck). I ended up using step 1, installing the Github Desktop client, adding a file, committing, syncing, and this created the master branch. But it would be much nicer to be able to initialize from the web frontend.

Answer (score -1):

In the image you provide the "readme", "license" and ".gitignore" links look active... I believe if you click one of those it will auto generate a file which is committed to the master branch for you

probably a bit late tho